# Explaing a grep command pattern

Tags: ubuntu, grep, command

I am going to apply this **grep** command for imputation in a genome file. Could you explain the what's the meaning of `'rs12722495 '` in this pattern? I have seen that it means nothing (using a pattern and after this pattern have a white space ). Is this pattern is correct? or It will be only  `'rs12722495'` (without space).

```
grep 'rs12722495 ' $TMP_DIR/tmp_impute2 >> $GEN_FILE
```

Comment: This question belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @Cyrus: Why? Is grep's behaviour different with respect to spaces in Ubuntu?

Comment: @choroba when I am using space in the pattern.it seems not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way than playing with spaces to avoid matching a superset, is to use grep's -w option- forces grep to match whole words.

Note that this would match lines like 'rs12722495,' which might not be what the OP really wants

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the pattern without the final space, you can accidentally match a different string of which your pattern is a substring, e.g. `rs127224950` (note the final zero). Specifying the space prevents that (provided the ids, or whatever else they are, are separated by spaces from the rest of the data).

Comment: Yes when I am applying without space it takes substring also.